# Date Validation (Date should not be in the range of existing date)

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, arraylist

I have a form in which the user can save their education details. Need a validation for this like date should not be in the range of existing qualification records.

What I have done so far is.

```
let eduList= this.var.educationResult;
  for(let i=0; i<= eduList.length-1; i++){      
        let startAndEnd = eduList[i][2].split('-');

        let existingFromYear= startAndEnd[0];
        let existingToYear = startAndEnd[1];

        let newFromYear= educationValues.fromDate.date.year;
        let newToYear= educationValues.toDate.date.year;

///Here I compared newly entered date with old education record dates.

      if((newFromYear > existingFromYear && newFromYear < existingToYear) || (newToYear> existingFromYear) && (newToYear < existingToYear) || (newFromYear === existingFromYear && newToYear === existingToYear)){
        toaster.error("Invalid Educational Details");
        this.validEdu = false;
        break;
      }
    }
```

It is working fine. But how to check with full date(with month and dates) for exact result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at moment.js

It will make handling dates very easy. There are other similar libraries out there (date-fns, luxon etc). You can use any of them.

```
moment('2010-01-01').isSame('2010-02-01', 'day'); //returns false
moment('2010-01-01').isSame('2010-01-01', 'day'); //returns true
```

Following is the link to what you are looking for.
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/

Comment: Thanks, @shubham Gupta

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of native javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects.
Use them for all of your dates (new ones as well as the existing ones).

When you have them, you can easily compare them. Simple example:

```
var dateNow = new Date();
var dateYesterday = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);

dateNow > dateYesterday //true
```

**Notice:** `moment.js` is an awesome library, with tons of possibilities for dates manipulation. However, the size of the library is quite big, and introducing a new dependency of this size to a project that exploits only its mere basics is unnecessary.